# Where to place user data file to be roamed along with Windows user's desktop settings?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell

I need to place some data from my process running under a logged in interactive user account into a persistent storage. The information in question is concerning user's desktop, screensaver, theme, and other desktop-related settings (in relation to my app.) I know that I can place this data as a binary key in the [HKEY_CURRENT_USER](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976337.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) registry key, but this data file can be somewhat large and I read somewhere that it's better not to put too much data into the System Registry.

So now I think I'll just save it in a binary file instead. The question is how do I find the appropriate location to save this file into? My main stipulation is that this file should "travel" (or `roam`) along with the logged in user's profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the best place is a sub-folder (named after your company or application so they use can identify where it came from) located under the `%APPDATA%` folder. You can get its location like this:

```
if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetKnownFolderPath ( FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, KF_FLAG_CREATE,
                                    NULL, &wszPath )))
{
    printf("\nSHGetKnownFolderPath FOLDERID_RoamingAppData = %S\n", wszPath);
}
```

There's more information on [Pat Altimore's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions.aspx).

Comment: Good article. Thank you. On the side note. Is my assumption correct, that the user's screensaver, its timing, as well as the display timeout are roaming with the user profile? Or are they local settings for a specific machine?

Comment: @c00000fd I would guess so, those settings are stored under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` so this would be part of the per-user profile.

Comment: @c00000fd: IIRC, they can also be fixed by Group Policy.